# Custom Built PC gets momentary power and immediately shuts down

Tags: computer-building

I built a custom pc with these parts: http://pcpartpicker.com/p/G66QMp

It turns on for a moment, giving enough time for energy to get to the cpu fan, but not enough to make it go a full rotation. I tried taking out a ram stick, but that didn't seem to effect the computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd probably start with some *specific* troubleshooting, then work my way down.

*First*, check the CPU power connector. Its  4-8 pins, labelled EPS12V usually on your PSU and its near the CPU

On your board check for the red freehand circled connector.
[image]

Then *remove* and replug in any and all power connectors. This is to make sure they're seated properly and so you can do a check to see if you *forgot* anything as you go along.

I'd also suggest removing the video card and trying to boot off onboard graphics if both of these fail to rule out the video card as well.

Comment: Over use of non required stand offs could also cause a short. But your thought on the four or eight pin Alt power to the mobo can and dose give the result the OP stated.

Comment: Thanks; I seem to have forgotten the CPU power connector, which caused my cpu not to run. Derp. :)

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the answer for the benefit of future visitors with the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

Could be your PSU's short-circuit protection kicking in, make sure there are no short-circuits on any of the power connectors and try unplugging cables from hardware one at a time until you find the culprit.

Either that or you haven't plugged one of the power cables into the motherboard.